# 21cm line of Hydrogen spectrum

Tags: astronomy, spectroscopy, hydrogen, radiometry

What is the advantage that we have when we study about 21cm line of Hydrogen spectrum over others, in radio-astronomy?

Comment: -1 No research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 21cm line falls in the microwave range of the electromagnetic spectrum, hence it's easily measurable from ground radiotelescopes. It's very useful, since is given from an hyperfine transition of the ground level of neutral Hydrogen atoms, and this can be used as a tracer for clouds of interstellar dust.
Other uses of the 21cm line is for calculating galactic rotation curves through doppler shift, since the frequency of that hyperfine transition is very well known

Answer (score 0):

> This wavelength falls within the microwave radio region of the electromagnetic spectrum, and it is observed frequently in radio astronomy, since those radio waves can penetrate the large clouds of interstellar cosmic dust that are opaque to visible light.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line)

So, we use that frequency because we can "see" into structures and areas that we can't with visible light or other frequencies of the electromagnetic spectrum.

It also passes through the earth's atmosphere without interference so any information we get is free from the distortions associated with trying to use visible light from the bottom of the atmosphere.